# Manipulating Dynamic object on C#

Tags: c#, reflection, xml-serialization

I have a C# class that inherits from DynamicObject and using serialization is creating me an instance for a given xml.

My issue: Now i have to generate one dynamic object from two equal (with same structure) xml files selecting some type of elements from the second xml only.

Do you have any link to any article where i could find techniques to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find some documentation:[Creating and Using Dynamic Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461504.aspx)

I think you can also use linq to xml for selecting the things that you need from the xml's.